# How to make compare in hashset and if second element is equal return the second value?

Tags: java, list, hashset

I need to compare two names in a hashset and if it is true change age1 to age2.
For example if user1 Max is equal user2 Max is true, 12 changed to 10. The main goal to use HashSet. And to compare it smth like this if(user1.contain ??? ) { user2.remove???

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleUser user1 = new SimpleUser("Max",12);
    SimpleUser user2 = new SimpleUser("Max",10);
    SimpleUser user3 = new SimpleUser("Tomek",50);

    Set<SimpleUser> group2 = new HashSet<>();
    group2.add(user1);
    group2.add(user2);
    group2.add(user3);

    System.out.println(group2);
```

for now my output is: 
[SimpleUser{name='Max', age=12}, SimpleUser{name='Tomek', age=50}]

```
my class User

    package com.company;

public class SimpleUser {
    private String name;
    private int age;

public SimpleUser(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    SimpleUser setUser = (SimpleUser) o;

    return name != null ? name.equals(setUser.name) : setUser.name == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SimpleUser{" + "name='" + name + '\'' + ", age=" + age + '}';


   }
}
```

Comment: You could call `group2.remove(user)` before adding `user`, or you could use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` instead.

Comment: could you expand your thought and explain me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you do not show relevant code, which presumably looks something like

```
class SimpleUser{
    String name;int age;
    SimpleUser(String name,int age){this.name=name;this.age=age;}
    public String toString(){return name+" "+age;}

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {return name.equals(((SimpleUser)obj).name);};

    public int hashCode() {return name.hashCode();};
}
```

Because if it was not this way, your 3 adds would result in 3 elements in the print.

Then comes [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)):

> `boolean add(E e)`
>
> Ensures that this collection contains the specified element (optional operation). Returns `true` if this collection changed as a result of the call. (Returns `false` if this collection does not permit duplicates and already contains the specified element.)

And indeed a `Set` does not permit duplicates, and "Max" is already present. `Set` does not "update", it just ignores re-adding an element (which it thinks is happening). Printing those `add`-s could have indicated what was happening too.

The simplest fix is removing any element before adding:

```
group2.remove(user1);group2.add(user1);
group2.remove(user2);group2.add(user2);
group2.remove(user3);group2.add(user3);
```

Comment: You are rigtht, added it to the main post. You solution is working but dont know is it true. Thanks)

Comment: @MaksymSereda You could always write ```if(group2.contains(newelement))group2.remove(newelement);```, just ```remove``` also does such check, so having it separately does not make the code better. And ```Set``` has no ```get``` operation as normally it would provide an identical object what one would be getting with. That is why others suggested ```Map<String,SimpleUser>```, which I would do too, just you explicitly write you are interested in a ```Set```

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on how lax the criteria for equality between two `SimpleUser`s is for you.

For instance, if two `SimpleUser` instances sharing the same name are in fact equal, then you should override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your `SimpleUser` class based on the `name` property.

Since `Set`s do not allow duplicate elements, an invocation of `add` for a `SimpleUser` whose name is already in the `Set` would return `false`, which would be a signal for you that the previous `SimpleUser` could be removed and the updated version of `Max` in this case could be added after.

This said, you do not necessarily need to change your (in-)equality criteria in `SimpleUser` if that doesn't fit well, and instead, search your `Set` for any `SimpleUser` named `Max` anyway and remove any before adding a new one.

The bottomline here being that unless you are using a `Map` (thus allowing a unique key set and an automatic replacement of values when invoking `put`, as Kayaman explains), the checking/merging operation will be manual.